# How to adjust webcam image on Skype?

Tags: skype, webcam, cheese

My Microsoft Lifecam VX-2000 webcam works with Skype and Cheese, but the image is a little dark on Skype. I adjust it on Cheese but the changes don't reflect in Skype (I think this was expected anyway). Also during the installation of Ubuntu when it prompts if I wanna take a picture with my webcam the image was crystal clear, in Cheese and Skype the image is a little curly.

How I can adjust the image to make it look brighter and less curly, if possible?

Comment: have you tried changing the settings using guvcview? It is a GUI interface for the Linux UVC devices.

Comment: Great application, I adjusted the image with him and now it's perfect. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: nice, i'll put it up as the answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [**guvcview**](http://guvcview.sourceforge.net/), which is a GTK+ interface for Linux USB Video Class (UVC) devices. It will allow you to make adjustments to the web camera.

To install this in Ubuntu via the terminal, type `sudo apt-get install guvcview`. Or you can install it via the Ubuntu Software Center or other dpkg-frontends.

Answer (score 0):

guvcview did not work for me. I could fix it with luvcview which has a setting called "Exposure". I had to decrease it, this reduced the framerate but improved the brightness as well.

Edit: Now, I have found out that guvcview seems to be more or less only a new GUI over luvcview. I have checked guvcview again and noticed that there is a scroll bar on the right side. There, you can also access the "Exposure"-setting.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu and thank you for contributing. Could you add how to install luvcview and where to find the settings?